# Php form not submitting, only get blank page using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

```
-php, PDO, prepared statement, html, bootstrap, mysql database-
```

whenever i hit submit button i get blank php page i.e:profile.php.i see no error or records inserted successfully. please can someone help me debug this code-----------------------------------------------------------------------.

```
<form action="profile.php" method="GET"> <!--enctype="multipart/form-data"-->
    <h1 >Profile </h1>
     <div class="form-row">        
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">        
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="fname" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">        
            <label>Age :</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Gender :</label>            
            <select  class="form-control" name="gender">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
            <label>Phone No :</label>            
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" required="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="phone" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
            <label>Address :</label>           
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="address"> </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Comments :</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments"> </textarea>
        </div>      

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Favorite Color :</label> 
            <br>            
            <input type="checkbox"  value="red" name="color[]" />Red
            <input type="checkbox" value="green" name="color[]" />Green
            <input type="checkbox" value="blue" name="color[]" />Blue
            <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" name="color[]" />Yellow
        </div>

    <!--    <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
            <label>Photo :</label>            
            <input type="file"  name="photo" />
        </div>-->

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="submit"   name="submit"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*this database connection code in dbconn.php and php code in profile.php*

```
<?php 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "pritesh";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            //$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            //echo "Connected successfully"; 
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
 ?>

<?php    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

include("dbconn.php");



$fname=$_REQUEST["fname"];
$age=$_REQUEST["age"];
$email=$_REQUEST["email"];          
$phone=$_REQUEST["phone"];
$address=$_REQUEST["address"];
$gender=$_REQUEST["gender"];
$color=$_REQUEST["color"];
$comments=$_REQUEST["comments"];


$sql = "insert into profile (name, age, email, phone, address, gender, color, comments) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);   
$stmt->bind_param($fname, $age ,$email, $phone, $address, $gender, implode(",",$color), $comments);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}

?>
```

Comment: use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST` .... for example `$fname=$_GET["fname"];`

Comment: also for `isset($_POST["submit"])` use `isset($_GET["submit"])` because you used `method="GET"` for your form

Comment: when i use method="GET" & isset($_GET["submit"]) & variable as $_GET. then i at least get error  " Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() ". BUT when i use method="POST" & isset($_POST["submit"]) & variable as $_POST. Then i see BLANK PHP . it s successfully connecting to database though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem is that you are calling accessing $conn without first checking whether it has been correctly created. This is a bad programming practice and can lead to problems. You should add an if clause to check what $conn is before you assume it's an object you can use.

Second similar assumption you make is call
    implode(",",$color)

$color being a variable received via $_REQUEST, yet you assume it is an array. Making assumptions such as this, especially from data which comes from a form submission is also a bad habit.

I would start debugging this issue by adding a check to see what $conn is before using it.